# Magento 2 CE Free extension / Module RMA or product return

Tags: magento2, magento-community, rma

Is there any Magento 2 Comunity Edition free extension for RMA ( product return ) ? or do you guys have create some own module to solve this lack in magento 2 Comunity Edition?

Comment: I hope there is a free RMA extension. But, currently, seem that there is no one. You should google.